# Move a specific part of text to next line if it have to

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to view a Name and rating value and a star in a single line but I am thinking of if the name gets larger than the star and rating must move collectively to the next line but in my condition it first rating moves then star, is there any possible solution that if moving to next line then both star and rating value

1. like

   ```
   Abdul* 4.5
   ```
2. if get more then

   ```
   Abdul Wahab
   *4.5
   ```
3. if bigger then

   ```
   Abdul Wahab 
   amir   *4.5
   ```

```html
<p className="Bold mb-0 FS_16 Black" style={{fontSize: "100%"}}> Any name
  <span>
    <img src={Star} alt="" className="mb-2 p-1" />
    <span className="Bold FS_16" style={{ color: "yellow" }}>{props.Rating}</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Add `<wbr>`  where you want the text to break

Comment: Just my 2 cents. The option 3 would look awful from UX point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if moving to next line then both star and rating value

Looks like you just need your rating to be solid block, so, you can force it to be solid with

```
<p className="Bold mb-0 FS_16 Black" style={{fontSize: "100%"}}> Any name
  <span className="rating">
    <img src={Star} alt="" className="mb-2 p-1" />
    <span className="Bold FS_16" style={{ color: "yellow" }}>{props.Rating}</span>
  </span>
</p>

.rating {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Or you can use `display: inline-flex` or whatever is better for your current layout and styling. You can also post your CSS, it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

A `p` element is a **block** element, it covers the whole width of its container and adds an **inline** box to its body where it can place **inline** elements. `span` and `img` elements are **inline** elements. **Inline** elements are subject to line-wrapping and you can place **inline** elements inside each other.

Solution: wrap the parts of the content where you DO NOT want line-breaking inside a `span` and set its css property `white-space` to `nobreak`. This content will then never line-break but this entire wrapping `span`, seen as an compund **inline** element in its surrounding may still break relative to other content in the surrounding box.

Check my primitive but meaningful samples and verify that the star and rating never separates with a line-break.

```css
.container { text-align: center; background-color: lightgreen; border: 1px solid black; }
.w25 { width: 25px; }
.w50 { width: 50px; }
.w100 { width: 100px; }
.w150 { width: 150px; }
.w200 { width: 200px; }
.nobreak { white-space: nowrap }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <div class="container w25">
      <p>
        <span>This is a name</span>
        <span class="nobreak">
          <span>&star;</span>
          <span>4.5</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container w50">
      <p>
        <span>This is a name</span>
        <span class="nobreak">
          <span>&star;</span>
          <span>4.5</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container w100">
      <p>
        <span>This is a name</span>
        <span class="nobreak">
          <span>&star;</span>
          <span>4.5</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
   <div class="container w150">
      <p>
        <span>This is a name</span>
        <span class="nobreak">
          <span>&star;</span>
          <span>4.5</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container w200">
      <p>
        <span>This is a name</span>
        <span class="nobreak">
          <span>&star;</span>
          <span>4.5</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```